# Admin Product page won't load due to excess attributes

Tags: magento2, magento2.1.5

**Magento 2.1.5**

I have an attribute set with 750 different attributes and each one is a drop down with 5-20 different options.

This causing an issue when trying to edit a product on the magento back end.  When I click on a product, the page never loads.  Despite many tries in different browsers and waiting hours, it never loads.

The obvious thing to say is "You have too many attributes.  Split them up."  That would be ideal, but I was given a database structured for ecommerce and it did not contain attribute sets.  It contains 85,000 products, so manually going through and creating attribute sets and then assigning all 85,000 products is not an option.

So what can I do?  Is there any way to increase the performance of the back end product pages?  Maybe delay the loading of the attribute options section unless clicked on?

Thanks for the help in advance.